Fuse causes boot to hang
ThinkPad X1 Carbon with Ubuntu 22.04.4.
Yesterday it started hanging on bootup. The very first bootup screen with the Lenovo logo and the TCO bubble. Would not respond to Enter (screen says it should) or any of the usual BIOS interrupt function keys. Disconnected dock and it boots fine on battery. Reconnected dock, tried to boot, unsuccessful, killed it, rebooted on battery, and looked at journalctl for the time of reboot. In the first few seconds there's
gnome-shell[1689]: endSessionDialog: No XDG_SESSION_ID, fetched from logind: 2
kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
systemd-logind[635]: System is rebooting.

and then lots and lots of stack trace messages. A web search on "No XDG_SESSION_ID" pointed a few places, but some of them implicated Fuse. I installed Fuse two days ago to be able to mount a Google drive. So I apt removed libfuse2 and the problem went away.
I may want to use Fuse again someday, so I have to figure out a long-term solution. Suggestions?
